# Excel Sumifs Returning 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

In the attached sheet, second tab, I have a table that is formulates to present the data spent in each country per month. Upon updating it I've seen that it does not work when adding in jan 2016. I have tried different formulas, rewriting, I know the formula is correct, there just has to be something about "Jan" where it's not adding data.

[Spend Matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zFCobQtTdAZr2OQfiQPIW_-OvOSpuCL5Vr4zTmbHCCg/edit?usp=sharing)

Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the code. The problem is in the data entry.

The year shows 15 although the year is supposed to be 16 and the SUMIFS criteria is in code "16"

ADDITION CODE

```
=SUMIFS(DB!F:F,DB!A:A,DB!A31299,DB!D:D,"16",DB!C:C,A16,DB!E:E,"United States")
```

The value of the country "Jamaica" is linked back to the DB cell to get its value, this seems to get it to work.

Comment: Check Again, the data entry has info for jan 2016, still not pulling anything. i wish it was that simple.

Comment: I rechecked again, the error seems to be caused by the data in A cell in the SUMIFS, i am unable to trace the error but i have a solution.

change the SUMIFS to the following:
=SUMIFS(DB!F:F,DB!A:A,DB!A31299,DB!D:D,"16",DB!C:C,A16,DB!E:E,"United States")

The value of the country "Jamaica" is linked back to the DB cell to get its value, this seems to get it to work.

Comment: rechecked again, the error seems to be caused by the data in A cell in the SUMIFS, i am unable to trace the error but i have a solution.

change the SUMIFS to the following:
=SUMIFS(DB!F:F,DB!A:A,DB!A31299,DB!D:D,"16",DB!C:C,A16,DB!E:E,"United States")

The value of the country "Jamaica" is linked back to the DB cell to get its value, this seems to get it to work.

Comment: Let me first say thank you, however, I have some into this solution before it's just too inconsistent of a solution for me to give in to. Hoping to find something else if possible.